# Multiple path animation on one object

Tags: animation, path

I'm still fairly new to blender, especially animation in blender and I have a question that might be easy to answer to an experienced blender user.

I have created multiple paths for an object (a model of a car) to follow, using Follow Path animation. I was able to make the car follow one or another, but my question is - how do I effectively convert the path animations to keyframes, and also, how do I save them as multiple animations for the car itself. The result should be something like 3 actions in the Action manager and switching between them would make the car switch between the animations.

To better illustrate what I'm trying to do, here is a screenshot of where I'm at at the moment.
[image: A car model and 3 nurbs paths]

I hope what I wrote is understandable. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The trick for animating a *Follow Path* modifier is to *not* enable *Animate Path* in the modifier, but, instead, to animate the followed Curve's *Evaluation Time*.  Here I've set up Suzanne to follow a simple Bezier Curve.

[image: Suzanne's Follow Path constraint]

(Ignore the background color of the Influence setting.  I'll come to that.)

To have Suzanne complete the circuit between, for instance, frame 1 and frame 12, I select the curve and go to its *Curve Properties* in the property editor and open the *Path Animation* panel.

[image: Path animation panel with Evaluation Time highlighted]

- Start following

  - Set the frame to 1
  - Set evaluation time to 0.0
  - Hover over the *Evaluation Time* input field and type <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe.
- Finish following

  - Set the frame to 12
  - Set evaluation time to 100.0 (This value should match *Frames*, above it)
  - Hover over the *Evaluation Time* input field and type <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe.

The problem comes when you have two path constraints.  So we go back to the Path constraint and set the influence.  Here I used a driver, which is why the background color of the constraint is what it is. (purple?)  Here are both constraints:

[image: Both constraints]

To create the driver select the *bottom* constraint in the stack.  Hover over the *Influence*  input, right click and select *Copy as New Driver*

To add the driver select the *top* constraint in the stack. Hover over the *Influence* input, right click and select *Paste Driver*.

Next, edit the driver by hovering over the top *Influence* input, right clicking and select *Edit Driver*  Change the type to *Scripted Expression* and set the expression to `1 - influence`.  Now you can control both influence values from the bottom.

[image: Driver editor showing changes]

When you want to follow the bottom curve, set its influence to 1 and keyframe it.
When you want to follow the top curve, set the *bottom* influence to 0 and keyframe it.  The driver will make the top influence the opposite value.